# How to construct a templated struct according to this example?

Tags: c++

Currently I'm learning about templates and structs. I need to do the following task:

> Create a struct template ConstInt with a static eval()
> method that returns the integer constant value.

Example:

```
typedef ConstInt<4> a; // represents the function a(x) = 4
```

I tried to do the following:

```
template<int value>
struct ConstInt
{
    static int  eval(int x)
    {
        return x; 
    };
};
```

But this doesn't seem to give the correct output. It gives an error when I try to do in the main():

```
typedef ConstInt<4> a;
```

> error: typedef 'a' locally defined but not used

I get an error, but I am not sure if this attempt was actually beneficial in order to complete the task.

Comment: It's a warning in 1st place, that you didn't use `a` anywhere. So just place a line like `int y = a::eval();` in `main()` for example. The warning is probably counted as error because you have `-Werror` with the compiler flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get an error, but I am not sure if this attempt was actually beneficial in order to complete the task.

The error you get, is a bit misleading regarding the correctness of your code.

> > ```
> > error: typedef 'a' locally defined but not used
> > ```

States that you didn't use the typedef you made. This can be fixed simply by using it.
That's a compiler warning under normal conditions, but counts as error if you set a compiler directive to handle warnings as errors (e.g. `-Werror` with g++).

The real problem is that you defined `eval()` with a parameter taken, but you don't need one, and you don't have one at your call of the function as mentioned in the example.

The correct struct definition and usage should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int value>
struct ConstInt {
    static int  eval() {
        return value; // the velue is already given as template parameter
    };
};

int main() {
    typedef ConstInt<4> a;
    int x = a::eval();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

See the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/834ea773a20b9f0e).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need if I understand your question correctly:

```
template<int value>
struct ConstInt
{
    static int  eval()
    {
        return value; // This returns the const value of a template parameter
    };
};
```

Then, you can typedef:

```
typedef ConstInt<4> a;
```

You can use the new typedef-ed a like this:

```
std::cout << a::eval();
```

It will print the number `4` into your screen.

Or, you can avoid typedef.

```
std::cout << ConstInt<4>::eval();
```

Answer (score 1):

This program will just return `0` as the exit value.

```cpp
template <int value>
struct ConstInt
{
   static int eval()
   {
      return value;
   };
};

int main()
{
   typedef ConstInt<4> a;
   return a().eval() - a::eval();
}
```

Here `a` is locally defined but it's also *used* twice on the next line in  different fashions.

Comment: _`a().eval();`_ Shouldn't that be `a::eval();`??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that works too :-). But you are allowed to call static member function on an object too.

Comment: Well sure, but obfuscates unnecessarily what's actually going on IMO.